# Latency of reading from a large array of i2c slaves?

Tags: microcontroller, i2c, latency

What kind of latency is involved into the polling of a large number of i2c slaves? I have an array of 64 i2c sensors slaves which need to send 2 bytes each to the master as rapidly as possible.

As far as I understand i2c, there is one bit for the start condition, 8 bits for the address and mode, then another bit for acknowledge, then the 16 bits of data, another acknowledge and the stop condition. Totaling at 28 bits per slave for the data and protocol overhead.

So, at 400 kbit, I should be able to hit about 223 reads from the entire array of slaves per second, or about 4.48 msecs for each sweep. Is that correct, or I am missing something?

Comment: Your general principal seems ok but I don't agree with your arithmetic - I make a single scan be 28*64*2.5 = 4480us.  This is about 200 times per second.

Comment: @KevinWhite - my bad, I divided 400k by 28 rather than by 28 * 64 as I should have.

Comment: Given that you mentioned that your slaves are MCUs and not limited to I2C, why not use SPI (or a somewhat reduced version thereof?)

Comment: @uint128_t - mostly because I have a bag of attiny85s which I was hoping to use, and they are kind of sparse on pins.

Comment: Have you considered 5 MHz Ultra Fast-mode, which is unidirectional?

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Would an attiny be able to to go that high? From what I read it is 400k max. Actually even 1 mhz would be nice and reduce sweep time to below 2 msecs, which is totally acceptable.

Comment: I2C has a 1.5MHz mode also.  Depends on the specs.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the part where slaves can do what is called *clock* stretching by holding the clock line for as long as they need to get ready.

So, without looking into the datasheet of each of your sensors, this will be impossible to answer.

However, many I²C devices simply don't do clock stretching, so your calculation might work out, if you add a bit of pause just to be sure everyone on the bus noticed the stop condition.

64 I²C slaves smells a lot like address collision (many I²C device types come with a fixed address, or maybe a set of 8 selectable addresses) – it might, very well, be possible that a different, possibly hierarchical bus architectures with microcontrollers polling "their" sensors and then communicating the "aggregate" data to the main MCU is much cleaner to handle. Especially considering that I²C is an externally pulled-up bus, and ensuring this works well with a 64-device bus is not really inherently trivial.

**Edit**: turns out each of your sensor is a microcontroller anyway.

Then, why not simply make a giant array of shift registers? SPI units are typically designed for exactly that purpose, and have shift registers internally. That way, you can make a daisy-chain of SPI devices, and save yourself the addressing overhead.

Comment: My "sensors" are just attiny's reading from piezos and pots. Each slave should have user configurable address, so it is up to the user to provide each sensor with a unique address. I was thinking of doing more of a "tree like" topology, but the overhead of switching alone doesn't seem to be that detrimental, so if possible, I'd like to hook the 64 slaves directly, after all, 127 outta be possible, even 1024 with 10 bit addressing. Also, if I do the tree thing, I will have to add more bytes so I can then parse which data comes from where, needless overhead and complexity as it seems.

Comment: ah, ok, if you decide on the addresses, yes, that will work. Really play close attention to pulling up the lines – with that many devices, you probably have a lot of parasitic capacitance on the I²C lines, and thus, you'll need low-value ("strong") pull up resistors, and you must hope your devices can deliver that much energy. I have an idea. Wait for my edit.

Comment: I am not really an expert in the field, could you provide some information about the wiring and operational principle of the suggestion from your edit?

Comment: Also, a clarification - I may have up to 64 slaves, but it is not a given, arbitrary configurations are possible, and even though all slaves report 2 bytes, those bytes mean different things. Will that be compatible with an array of shift registers, because it kind of sounds like the configuration needs to be static and known in advane in order for this to work? Whereas with i2c slaves what I plan to do is probe the connected slaves and determine the order of operation accordingly.

Comment: @ddriver  Since you've got intelligent sensors nodes, you could consider some form of data compression.  For example, if the readings from the sensor have't changed since last time it was polled, is transmits 1 byte instead of 2.  To keep errors from accumulating, it transmits full payload every 8th poll even if readings haven't changed.

Comment: @ddriver yes, for the shift register thing, the constellation has to be static and known. Frankly, this is a pretty interesting discussion, but the more I think about it, the more I wish you'd have a separate question where you describe your sensor network, the job and distribution of the individual sensors etc., and explain your I2C based approach and ask for topology advice (link to it here of you do ask that question)

Comment: @NickAlexeev - some resurrection, compression is not really applicable in a 2 byte scenarios. And while it is possible to transmit a 0 byte to indicate no data, the usage scenario, as implied by the question title, is latency sensitive, so postponing is not an option. Cascading/aggregation might be an option, but it complicates the topology and increases the hardware requirements.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - the usage scenario is electronic drums, which is also why it is latency sensitive. But unlike the regular approach that involves just a single piezo per pad, each pad incorporates an mcu that does some logic and dsp for some extra functionality like better hit detection, multiple piezos and zones and so on. The requirement is that the user should be able to build custom sets depending on needs and preferences, use an 8 position dip switch to give every pad a unique address, while pads themselves report their specific type during the initialization phase.

Comment: hm, what info does a single drum pad need to communicate to the host? And: your application damn much sounds like it's asking for an interrupt-driven system, not a "queried" bus. But that might just be me.

Comment: It depends on the type of pad, a drum pad needs to report type (skin or rim), position (for skin only) and velocity, a cymbal pad needs to report choke (that's muting it by squeezing it with the palm), position and velocity. I've already accounted for squeezing all that data as tight as possible, within the confines of 2 bytes in case there is any data present.

Comment: Yes interrupts are also a possibility but it seems to complicate things quite a bit. It will definitely be able to cut latency by not processing idle pads, but it raises the question how applicable is to have a dynamic array of up to 64 devices that do interrupts, and it is worth it. The key here is to keep latency below the perceivable value, which is about 10 msec, so if I am able to get about 5 or lower (by transmitting a single idle bit) that would suffice. There should be no hold up, a pad will either have data to transmit or not.

Comment: why does it complicate things? A human will have a hard time causing more than two interrupts in 10ms, and that seems something absolutely doable in bus systems where devices can initiate a transfer. CAN?

Comment: @MarcusMüller `A human will have a hard time causing more than two interrupts in 10ms` - a human has two hands and two feet, which can strike simultaneously well within the range of 10 msec. There is also drumstick tremolo, there is simultaneous rim and skin hit, there is variance in cymbal choke and hi-hat pedal. There is also drum bleed, which is vibrations that one pad transfers to other pads through the drumkit frame, which might sound undesirable, but actually has immense value for realism, whereas isolated pads sound very artificial.

Comment: so, how exactly will that make the interrupt-based system harder to implement? It's still a lower bound for the latency you incur when asking every single device.

Comment: The point is in most cases hitting any pad will result in at least several pads reporting some data almost simultaneously. Also, I am not that familiar with mcu capabilities, but considering the number of IRQs big multicore desktop systems have, it seems that a tiny single core mcu might not be able to handle 64 of those. And skipping pads is not an option, therefore my initial approach at sweeping all of them.

Comment: I didn't mean the MCU's software to be interrupt driven (there'd be at most one involved here – new data from the bus), but the bus to be driven by a device just raising its voice to announce it has something to say, which makes subsequent devices wait until it's done.

Comment: That does sound like it could be a good idea. I will look into it. Although it does seem like devices might end up fighting for bus time. Is there a way to ensure no slave gets left out for too long? Or are retries more of a lottery, whichever one happens to catch the bus free takes it? It would be nice if subsequent slaves acquire the bus in the order they were denied it, but it doesn't look like there is such an option, at least not an obvious one.

Comment: Also, it occurs to me that I can cut down time for slaves that have no data to report by simply not acknowledging, and cutting the overhead from idle slaves down by half. It is actually redundant to send entire 8 bits just to send a null byte to inform there is no new data.

Answer (score -1):

> As far as I understand i2c

it depends on how the slave is structured. a typical process involves sending the device id + write, and then the address; restart, and then device id, read two bytes. so for a total of 5 bytes. 9 bits per byte, that's about 50 bits per device.

the rest of the math is easy.

> as rapidly as possible.

then you picked the wrong protocol. i2c is the opposite of "fast".

Comment: There is no "address" involved here aside from the slave address, or as you put it - the id, the slave doesn't need to be told what to do.